# How to deserialize dodgy JSON (with improperly quoted strings, and missing brackets)?

Tags: arrays, json, json.net

I am having to parse (and ultimately reserialize) some dodgy JSON. it looks like this:

```
{
  name: "xyz",
  id: "29573f59-85fb-4d06-9905-01a3acb2cdbd",
  status: "astatus",
  color: colors["Open"]
},
{
  name: "abc",
  id: "29573f59-85fb-4d06-9905-01a3acb2cdbd",
  status: "astatus",
  color: colors["Open"]
}
```

There are a number of problems here - starting with the most severe.

1. `color: colors["Open"]`

   WTF even is that? If I drop 'colors' then I can get an array of strings out but I can't tweak to work out of the box.
2. It is an array without square brackets. I can fix this by wrapping in them. But is there a way to support out of the box?
3. Properties have no quotes. Deserializing is fine for these.. but reserializing is just no dice.

Any suggestions of handling both in and out of this structure?

Comment: you can't use a standard JSON parser to parse that, because it's not valid JSON. You'd have to write your own, or find a way to manipulate the incoming string before you hand it to the parser. Clearly the best solution is to fix the dodgy data source, but are we to understand that is beyond your control? What on earth is pumping out this junk and calling is JSON? Most programming languages now have built-in JSON serialisation tools, so it should actually be pretty hard to produce invalid output.

Comment: You're asking multiple questions at once.  The preferred format is [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735/344280).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your questions #1 - #3 in order:

1. Json.NET does not support reading dodgy property values in the form `colors["Open"]` (which, as you correctly note, violates the [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/)).

   Instead, you will need to manually fix these values, e.g. through some sort of `Regex`:

   ```
   var regex = new Regex(@"(colors\[)(.*)(\])");
   var fixedJsonString = regex.Replace(jsonString, 
       m => string.Format(@"""{0}{1}{2}""", m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value.Replace("\"", "\\\""), m.Groups[3].Value));
   ```

   This changes the `color` property values into properly escaped JSON strings:

   ```
   color: "colors[\"Open\"]"
   ```

   Json.NET does, however, have the capability to *write* dodgy property values by calling [`JsonWriter.WriteRawValue()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_WriteRawValue.htm) from within a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm).

   Define the following converter:

   ```
   public class RawStringConverter : JsonConverter
   {
       public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
       {
           return objectType == typeof(string);
       }

       //Comment out or return true if you want the current token to be deserialized as a raw value rather than as a JSON string primitive.
       //The token must still represent well-formed JSON.
       public override bool CanRead { get { return false; } }

       public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           return JRaw.Create(reader).ToString();
       }

       public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           writer.WriteRawValue((string)value);
       }
   }
   ```

   Then define your `RootObject` as follows:

   ```
   public class RootObject
   {
       public string name { get; set; }
       public string id { get; set; }
       public string status { get; set; }

       [JsonConverter(typeof(RawStringConverter))]
       public string color { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   Then, when re-serialized, you will get the original dodgy values in your JSON.
2. Support for deserializing comma-delimited JSON without outer brackets will be in the next release of Json.NET after [10.0.3](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/10.0.3).  see [Issue 1396](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1396) and [Issue 1355](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1355) for details.  You will need to set   [`JsonTextReader.SupportMultipleContent = true`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadMultipleContentWithJsonReader.htm) to make it work.

   In the meantime, as a workaround, you could grab `ChainedTextReader` and `public static TextReader Extensions.Concat(this TextReader first, TextReader second)` from the answer to [`How to string multiple TextReaders together?`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925722) by [Rex M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67/rex-m) and surround your JSON with brackets `[` and `]`.

   Thus you would deserialize your JSON as follows:

   ```
   List<RootObject> list;
   using (var reader = new StringReader("[").Concat(new StringReader(fixedJsonString)).Concat(new StringReader("]")))
   using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader))
   {
       list = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().Deserialize<List<RootObject>>(jsonReader);
   }
   ```

   (Or you could just manually surround your JSON string with `[` and `]`, but I prefer solutions that don't involve copying possibly large strings.)

   Re-serializing a root collection without outer braces is possible if you serialize each item individually using its own `JsonTextWriter` with [`CloseOutput = false`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_CloseOutput.htm).  You can also manually write a `,` between each serialized item to the underlying `TextWriter` shared by every `JsonTextWriter`.
3. Serializing JSON property names without a surrounding quote character is possible if you set [`JsonTextWriter.QuoteName = false`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextWriter_QuoteName.htm).

   Thus, to re-serialize your `List<RootObject>` without quoted property names or outer braces, do:

   ```
   var sb = new StringBuilder();
   bool first = true;
   using (var textWriter = new StringWriter(sb))
   {
       foreach (var item in list)
       {
           if (!first)
           {
               textWriter.WriteLine(",");
           }
           first = false;
           using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(textWriter) { QuoteName = false, Formatting = Formatting.Indented, CloseOutput = false })
           {
               JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().Serialize(jsonWriter, item);
           }
       }
   }

   var reserializedJson = sb.ToString();
   ```

Sample [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/o0ns2N) showing all this in action.