# Cannot parse json with Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, regex, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize this json:

```
{"name":"FC Internazionale Milano","y":55},{"name":"AC Chievo Verona","y":45,"sliced":true}
```

which is available inside that function that's contained in a string:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
var chart = new PieChart('Possession');
     chart.addSeries('Possession', [{"name":"FC Internazionale Milano","y":55},{"name":"AC Chievo Verona","y":45,"sliced":true}]);

chart.highChartsOptions.plotOptions.pie.topmargin = '20';
chart.highChartsOptions.plotOptions.pie.size = "80%";
chart.highChartsOptions.plotOptions.pie.center = ['50%', '55%'];
    chart.render('page_chart_1_chart_statsplus_1_chart_possession_1-wrapper');

});
```

for the get json I used this regex:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(script, @"Possession[^\{]+(.*})").Groups[1].Value;
```

which return the json above. So I deserialized in this way:

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonMatchStat>(jsonStr);
```

the structure of `JsonMatchStat` is this:

```
 public class JsonMatchStat
 {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
    public bool? sliced { get; set; }
 }
```

when I deserialize the json I get:

> 'Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: ,. Path '', line 1, position 42.'

what I did wrong?

Comment: This is not valid JSON, it looks like multiple JSON files stitched together with commas.

Comment: I'm no JSON expert but there are two classes in that JSON string. Is this the issue?

Comment: those are two objects you want to deserialize as one, make it a list like [{"name":"FC Internazionale Milano","y":55},{"name":"AC Chievo Verona","y":45,"sliced":true}] and deserialize to a list instead var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonMatchStat>>(jsonStr);

Comment: @fantaghiro, it seems you already have an answer

Comment: Actually, reading a comma-delimited sequence of JSON objects is supported natively in Json.NET [11.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/11.0.1).  See [How to deserialize dodgy JSON (with improperly quoted strings, and missing brackets)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46788778/3744182).  You need to set `JsonReader.SupportMultipleContent = true`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The JSON you have extracted isn't valid, it's multiple JSON objects stitched together with commas. The problem is that you have missed off the surrounding `[` and `]` brackets that indicate the JSON is an array. So instead if you have Regex to include them (note: I'm no Regex expert, but this should work):

```
Possession[^\[]+(.*}\])
```

Now you can deserialise to an enumerable:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<JsonMatchStat>>(jsonStr);
```