# Get value within the CDATA within tab delimited text file using C#

Tags: c#, xml, cdata

I have a string value in the column as  in a tab demilited text file and want to extract the value within it 'John Smith' and store it in as a string value.I tried using string.Replace but not sure of the I have the correct implementation for it.

```
     string cdatastring = "<![CDATA[John Smith]]>";
     string expected = "John Smith";
```

How do I implement it using C#/.NET methods?

Comment: Please read [ask], and post a [mcve].  Thank you.

Comment: done, let me know if the example is verifiable

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview) method [`XElement.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb468714.aspx) to parse any well-formed XML document, however your CDATA string `<![CDATA[John Smith]]>` is not a well-formed XML document, it's just a document *fragment*, since it lacks a [root element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element).  To convert it to well-formed XML, you can surround it by a synthetic root element, parse that, and extract the [value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value.aspx) like so:

```
var value = XElement.Parse("<a>" + cdatastring + "</a>").Value;
```

If your `cdatastring` is longer than 42,000 characters or so and thus the string with the added root element would go on the [large object heap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8951836), you could grab `ChainedTextReader` and `public static TextReader Extensions.Concat(this TextReader first, TextReader second)` from the answer to [*How to string multiple TextReaders together?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925722) by [Rex M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67/rex-m) and create the following extension method:

```
public static class XmlExtensions
{
    public static XElement ParseFragment(string xmlFragment)
    {
        using (var reader = new StringReader("<a>").Concat(new StringReader(xmlFragment)).Concat(new StringReader("</a>")))
        {
            return XElement.Load(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

Then extract your CDATA value like so:

```
var value = XmlExtensions.ParseFragment(cdatastring).Value;
```

Sample working .Net fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lNed6S).